# Labeled bar chart with fill encoding does not respect sorting

Tags: vega-lite

I am trying to make a sorted bar chart with labels and `fill` encoding. But when I add the the fill encoding it breaks the sort. Via the github issues it seems like there are ways to get around this, but I can seem find a solution.

Given the spec without using the fill encoding the sorting works as expected.

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "a": "A",
        "b": 28,
        "color": "black"
      },
      {
        "a": "B",
        "b": 55,
        "color": "grey"
      },
      {
        "a": "C",
        "b": 43,
        "color": "red"
      }
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "a",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "sort": {
        "encoding": "x",
        "order": "descending"
      }
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar"
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": 3
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "b",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: sorted baar]

When you add the fill encoding to the top level encoding object it breaks the sort with the following warning

```js
"fill": {
  "field": "color",
  "type": "ordinal",
  "scale": null
}
```

```
[Warning] Domains that should be unioned has conflicting sort properties. Sort will be set to true.
```

[image: filled bar]

[Full vega-editor here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5QECJAroxrZLGxgA2hsNgD9w5D1QAgmrtPI7KwCYADnUnZ3huMW4AJysfMXR4AGtILwgAX2CnRxCXGIAhTxCjXxwAVhKM7LCI6JxIakjkAE9kkPSUh3ajV0gAYQLCnysAFmkK7yqomIbNFqdUrwBdDTajZCUwzUYlaissqGb9dsgAM0ZkMRnazDGjPEbCZBiozaVTfvtIRUi8Xc6oNY2Wx2tQAHu9vM9kDUtBZ4GsXjt2vN7CtnGDDtlTudLlBfDcoHcHjEAI6sdBKPDMHSMKizNJjE6MMRiX6Ys4XGITaL4yCEx61Z5bN48hCmflgJSsZleZFgVGQOKNKFWWz2PZGDCRJK1djoaIysbqqCa7UdQoE+7i3nIEE-fFdCTUFS1MTIY52v4+dCwc5bK2oRiaTSu8EfTTosDSJE8gHcBGsgZ4G0-DHmqBYjk60PePkkskUqmU2l-WUomUaJapIA)

Is there a work around for this.

It appear to relate to the these issues (maybe) [#2536](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/2536), [#5408](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5048)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, the underlying issue is https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5048. In this particular case, adding color to once layer adds a stack transform to one part of the dataflow but not the other so we cannot merge it. This is a great test case. Can you add this example to a new github issue so we can try to resolve it?

You can manually fix this example by disabling stacking the x encoding.

```
"stack": null
```

See [this spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5QECJAroxrZLGxgA2hsNgD9w5D1QAgmrtPI7KwCYADnUnZ3huMW4AJysfMXR4AGtILwgAX2CnRxCXGIAhTxCjXxwAVhKM7LCI6JxIakjkAE9kkPSUh3ajV0gAYQLCnysAFmkK7yqomIbNFqdUrwBdDTajZCUwzUYlaissqGb9dsgAM0ZkMRnazDGjPEbCZBiozaVTfvtIRUi8Xc6oNY2Wx2tQAHu9vM9kDUtBZ4GsXjt2vN7CtnGDDtlTudLlBfDcoHcHjEAI6sdBKPDMHSMKjgoywXSJKxKVhiMReVFGU5s36Ys4XGITaL4yCEx61Z5bN4ihCmcVgFlsjnLDKQOKNKFWWz2PZGDCRJK1djoaIcsa6qD6w0dQoE+7y0XIEE-fFdCTUFS1MTIY4uv4+dCwc5bB2oRiaTTeunOTTosDSJEigHcBG8gZ4J0-DG2qBYgVG6MfMUkskUqmU2l-ZFzZUQJapIA).

[image]